# Homemade replacement for no-ip service

Tags: networking, nas

I have a NAS setup where I have one local NAS and one distant NAS which is at place with dynamic IP.

At the distant place, the "internet-box" (French SFR) has a possibility to use no-ip (www.noip.com) out of the box (DynDNS) so that my local NAS can upload data to that distant NAS over a abc.def.com address instead of over a 123.123.123.123 address (which wouldn't work as it's dynamic).

The no-ip is not free though (or you have to valitade not so often but with a 7-days limit when it happens).

So my question is, can I/how can I (if even possible) set up a no-ip service of my own on, for example, on my webserver?

Thanks!